# What is the pattern for setting attributes on Backbone.js' Models and Views?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, backbone.js

I am new to the world of Javascript frameworks and I really like the way Backbonejs works.
But I have one question regarding the constructors of Models and Views. I have developed for years using Java like languages, and I am used to define constructors like this:

```
public Car(Manufacturer manufacturer, String model, Color color) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
}
```

But I see in the documentation and in other tutorials that people usually don't declare a specific constructor when defining a Model or View, and they just construct objects like this:

```
var car = new Car({manufacturer: ford, model: "Mustang", color: "red"});
```

Is it wrong or "ugly" to define a constructor like:

```
window.Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(manufacturer, model, color) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
    }
});
```

If so, can you explain why ?
I really hope this is not a stupid question, I have not found any related questions.

Comment: It's not Java. Don't expect it to follow the exact same grammar.

Comment: Thank you for your comment asawyer! Actually, I don't expect the same grammar, I just want to know what is the right/best approach, once both are possible.

Comment: If you define your class this way, would you have access to `initialize` when creating an instance of your `CarModel`?

Comment: I'm sorry MilkyWayJoe, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of passing in multiple arguments rather than an object is fine, however you would want the initialize function to look like this:

```
window.Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(manufacturer, model, color) {
        this.set({
            manufacturer: manufacturer,
            model: model,
            color: color
        });
    }
});
```

You need to use `set` to access the attributes object. By using `this` you are attaching the attributes directly to the model.

The reason that backbone uses the attributes object is so that it can automaticaally trigger events when you change attributes. It is also a way to encapsulate your fields in methods, in the same way you would create

`private Manufacturer manufacturer;`

and

`public Manufacturer getManufacturer()`

in java.

Comment: Thank you Greg Guida! This way I don't feel I am corrupting something.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to passing a context object to  a method in Java (which is done where you need to pass some state to a method in a stateless environment).  It just happens that the method is a constructor. I don't think there is a specific official pattern for this.    This is a common paradigm in javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer hvgotcodes! But I see that if I define initialize as a constructor with params like `function(man,model,color)` and use **this** variable to define the models attributes, I can't access those attributes using the **get** method of the model, but I can access the attribute directly `car.model`. Is there any implications eg. in Backbone events on models attributes, depending the way I define these attributes ?